# Php code inside style tag of html not working

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make my sub category looks different when it's selected, for that I've used sub_cat variable in my php.
So value of $sub_cat depends on the page that loads.
On the top I've this code:

```
if(!empty($_GET['sub_cat'])){
        $sub_cat=$_GET['sub_cat'];
    }
    else{
        $sub_cat=0;
    }
```

Now what my code for displaying list.

```
<li <?php if($sub_cat==11) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?> ><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=11">Popular</a></li>
<li <?php if($sub_cat==12) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?> ><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=12">Exotic</a></li>
<li <?php if($sub_cat==13) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?> ><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=13">Fibrous Veg</a></li>
```

But it doesn't seem to make any difference, value of $sub_cat is coming fine as in 11,12,13 but this code is not working. Can anyone spot the minor mistake or major mistake?

Comment: what do you mean by not working?

Comment: I'm confused, there's no css differences in your sub-cats

Comment: It's not changing the color of elements of li, by default color is black, so what I want to achieve is if sub_Cat is 11, color of 'Popular'(first list element) should be changed to #C00

Comment: are you sure `$sub_cat` is 11 or 12 or 13 , and nothing else ?

Comment: Yes, it's 11,12 or 13. Even I echoed the value of $sub_cat & it's 11.

Comment: do this : `style='color:#C00 !important'`

Comment: Have you taken a look at the HTML to make sure no styles are being echoed?

Comment: View source code of the output in the browser

Comment: @AlirezaFallah That didn't work, but answer given below worked fine. Just place the php inside a tag & not in li.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about transferring the `style` attribute to the `a` element instead of placing it in the `li`.

```
<li><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=11" <?php if($sub_cat==11) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?>>Popular</a></li>
<li><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=12" <?php if($sub_cat==12) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?>>Exotic</a></li>
<li><a href="vegetables.php?sub_cat=13" <?php if($sub_cat==13) echo "style='color:#C00'"; ?>>Fibrous Veg</a></li>
```

Comment: This is probably right. `a` elements have default colors, they don't inherit from the container.

Comment: God, that worked, but what difference did it make??:/

Comment: I think the `a` elements don't inherit from their parents and have their own values for colors. What you did could work if you add a `color: inherit` to the CSS rules of your `a` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_GET['sub_cat'])){
        $sub_cat=$_GET['sub_cat'];
    }
    else{
        $sub_cat=0;
    }
```

Comment: Value of sub_cat is already coming fine, no need to change that code.